# What unit of time/ date format is being used for the argument in this DATE function?

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I'm having a hard time figuring out what date format I need to pass to this DATE() function on what I believe is an older T-SQL procedure.

As an example, It works in such a way that `DATE(1473811)` ends up giving me `'02-27-4036'`. It's not milliseconds, seconds, or days since the unix epoch. I'm totally confused on what unit of time or format this could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would appear to be the number of days since 0001-00-00.

That said, I am not sure which calendar is being used for this purpose.  However, on Postgres, the following:

```
select date('4036-02-27') - 1473811 * interval '1 day'
```

returns Dec 31 of the year 1 BC.

Note:  I realize the question is tagged "tsql" and not "Postgres", but the date format does not seem to be a tsql standard format.

Comment: Yea, I tagged it tsql since thats what I think this old as400 is based off of, but I'm not sure on that. Thanks for the answer. Rather than the days since 0000-00-00 though, according to this http://www.epochconverter.com/seconds-days-since-y0 that I used to check it out, it's actually the days since 0001-01-01. Days since 0000-00-00 gives me todays date next year. Now to just figure out if I can get that number from a YYYYMMDD integer format using SQL....

Comment: @zero01alpha . . . You are right.  There is no year zero.  One day before "0001-01-01" is "-0001-12-31" (or 0001-12-31 BC).